# Left join including a where condition not working

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, left-join

I’m going nuts.  It seems everyone has had this same problem by the number of results I get when I google ‘left join not working’.   I’ve studied them all and despite best efforts I cannot get my specific problem to work.  Please help.

I have two tables; an animals_Table and an animalMilestones_Table.

Some of the animals in the animals_Table have intake records in the animalMilestones_Table and some do not.   I want to join the two tables on animalID and show all rows in the animals_Table including those that have no matching ‘Intake’ record in the animalMilestones_Table.

Here are the two things I’ve tried that I thought would give the best chance for success but alas, neither work.

```
SELECT animals_Table.animalID, animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN animalMilestones_Table ON animals_Table.animalID=animalMilestones_Table.animalID
WHERE animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType="Intake"

SELECT animalID
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT milestoneType
FROM animalMilestones_Table
WHERE animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType = "Intake")
ON animals_Table.animalID = animalMilestones_Table.animalID
```

Comment: The problem is that your WHERE clause is limiting the complete resultset. What you put there, you should make part of the LEFT JOIN (using AND)

Comment: are you sure there are records with same id's and which have `milestoneType="Intake"` in `animalMilestones_Table` table?

Comment: I've tried taking out the where and putting the condition in the join expression and I keep getting 'join expression not supported'. For illustration purposes assume I have four animals (animalID = 1, 2, 3, and 4).  In the animalMilestone_Table I have 10 records of varying milestoneTypes.  Two of the four animals in the animals_Table have corresponding milestoneTypes of "Intake".  I want to show all four animals in the result set.  I think MS-Access is just very particular about how this is done and it's causing big problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want a list of all [animalID] values from [animals_Table] along with a column that indicates whether or not that [animalID] has a "milestone" equal to 'Intake'. If so, then I would suggest this:

```sql
    SELECT at.animalID, amt.milestoneType
    FROM
        animals_Table at
        INNER JOIN
        animalMilestones_Table amt
            ON at.animalID = amt.animalID
    WHERE amt.milestoneType = 'Intake'
UNION
    SELECT animalID, NULL AS milestoneType
    FROM animals_Table
    WHERE animalID NOT IN (
        SELECT animalID
        FROM animalMilestones_Table
        WHERE milestoneType = 'Intake'
    )
ORDER BY 1
```

Come to think of it, this should work too, and may prove to be faster:

```
SELECT at.animalID, amt.milestoneType
FROM
    animals_Table at
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT animalID, milestoneType
        FROM animalMilestones_Table
        WHERE milestoneType = 'Intake'
    ) amt
        ON at.animalID = amt.animalID
```

Comment: Thank you Gord; your code does exactly what I need it to do.  Perfect.  I could never have gotten this on my own.  I read about Union today and thought that this might be the answer to my problem but it looked like it was going to be too hard for me to figure out.  And, it would have been.  It's a shame that 'left join' doesn't work as advertised but at least there is a way to get it done.  Great job Gord and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2076963 You're welcome. FYI, I just added a LEFT JOIN solution as well.

Comment: Excellent, Gord!  This left join solution performs better.  It's a lot quicker than the UNION solution and I'm going to put it in my code right away.  I've struggled with this for days but now it's solved and I can get back to finding the next thing that will cause me to struggle for days. :)  Can't thank you enough.  And much thanks to everyone who worked hard on this for me.

Comment: I've tried building the left join solution into my vb.net form and for some reason it's not working.  I cannot find my mistake.  I'm going to post a new question and I hope you'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType will be NULL in cases where there is no record. You need to check for it being NULL or the value you are querying for.

```
animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType="Intake" or animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType is null
```

Not sure on the exact SQL syntax in Accesss

Comment: I get the same results as if the 'is null' condition is not there. The record that would contain the milestoneType = "Intake" doesn't exist; it's not that the record exists and field is null.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if MS Access supports this, but in SQL you would move your condition from the `WHERE` clause into the `LEFT JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT animals_Table.animalID, animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN animalMilestones_Table ON animals_Table.animalID=animalMilestones_Table.animalID AND animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType="Intake"
```

Comment: @abalos All good! Our answers were less than 20 seconds apart :-)

Answer (score 0):

maybe the code below work for you.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   animals_table at
LEFT JOIN animalmilestones_table amt ON at.animalID = amt.animalID AND amt.milestoneType = "Intake"
```

Please, try it out and tell me how it goes.

Comment: No, it's the same as suggested above and I get 'join expression not supported'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT animals_Table.animalID, animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT milestoneType
FROM animalMilestones_Table
WHERE milestoneType = "Intake") as animalMilestones_Table
ON animals_Table.animalID = animalMilestones_Table.animalID;
```

Comment: I get an error message like this: the animalMilestones_Table.animalID could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.  That's wacky because it specifies the table.

Comment: Try this

`SELECT animals_Table.animalID, table2.milestoneType
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN (SELECT milestoneType
FROM animalMilestones_Table
WHERE milestoneType = "Intake") as table2
ON animals_Table.animalID = table2.animalID;`

Comment: It prompts me for values and when I enter a valid value it returns nothing.   I tried replacing table2 with animalMilestones_Table and removing the AS statement and got invalid syntax.   Your suggestion, from everything I've read and studied, should work.  But yet it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

try out the following query. hope this may help you and let me know if this helps..

```
SELECT animals_Table.AnimalID, animalMilestones_Table.MileStoneType
FROM animals_Table LEFT JOIN animalMilestones_Table ON animals_Table.AnimalID = animalMilestones_Table.AnimalID
WHERE ((((animalMilestones_Table.MileStoneType)='Intake' Or (animalMilestones_Table.MileStoneType) like '*') Or (animalMilestones_Table.MileStoneType) Is Null)) ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it omits animals in the animals_Table that don't have an 'Intake' record in the animalMilestones_Table.  The result set omits animals and I want to show every animal in the animals table regardless of any corresponding records each may have in the animalMilestones_Table.

Comment: It doesn't work.  It does get all the animals (desired) but it yields rows that have milestoneTypes other than 'Intake'.  I get rows for 'Birth', 'Adoption', etc. and these are not desired.

Comment: @user2076963 will you please describe what exactly the output should be?

As you earlier said that you want all records from animals_Table and now you are saying i want only the records having milestone type 'Intake'.

please make clear what exactly is your requirement.

Comment: I'll have to give a better example and I'll think of how I can do that.  I do want all records from the animals table.  And for those animals that have intake records I want to show data for those records. And for those animals that don't have intake records blanks would show in the result set.   I'll try to give sample data next.

Comment: 1 
2 Intake
3 
4 Intake
5 
6 
 
The above is the result set I would like to see if it came from an animals_Table with six records with ID's 1 thru 6.  But only animals 2 and 4 have records with milestoneType = "Intake" in the animalMilestones_Table.  Understand?

Comment: Oops, I inserted a table as an example and it didn't come thru as expected (a table).  So, you probably can't envision the result set I would like.

Comment: so you want all the records from animals_Table that have Correspondingly records in animalMilestones_Table whether it is 'Intake' or something else except blank. am i right?

Comment: No.  I want all the records in the animals_Table period.  All of them.  And, for the ones that have corresponding "Intake" records in the amt then I want to show information from them.  Thanks for continuing to take an interest in this AG.

Answer (score -1):

Does:

```
SELECT animals_Table.animalID, animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType
FROM animals_Table
LEFT JOIN animalMilestones_Table ON animals_Table.animalID=animalMilestones_Table.animalID
AND animalMilestones_Table.milestoneType="Intake"
```

Work?

Comment: No, if gives me 'join expression not supported'.  I forgot to mention I'm querying MS Access which I'm sure is a little different.

Comment: Change "Intake" to 'Intake' as well.  Single quotes in SSMS.

Comment: single quotes gave me the same thing; 'join expression not supported'.

Comment: My bad.  I didn't see that this was MS-Access.  I don't use that for anything.  Thought it was SQL Server.